# How to see the last commit in my Gitosis server and date of that

Tags: git, gitosis

I want to see the last activity on my Gitosis server, because we have a new service (Gitorious) and we think that Gitosis has been forgotten by the users.
I can use this to see the numbers of commits:

```sh
cd /path/to/repos/ && ls | xargs -I % git --git-dir=% rev-list --all 2>/dev/null | wc -l
```

but this only shows the number, not the date.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `--pretty` option, eg.

```
git show --pretty='format:%h %ai'
```

See [git-show](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-show.html#_pretty_formats) for more information on "pretty" formats.